# Is it possible to derive the formula of the gravitational potential energy without using the formula for the force?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, education

Clearly one can derive the formula for the gravitational potential Energy by just integrating the force $$F_{\mathrm{G}} ~=~ \gamma \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2},\tag{1}$$ i.e.

$$
E_{\mathrm{pot}}(r)~=~- \int^r_{\infty} d\vec{\rho}\cdot \vec{F}_{\mathrm{G}}
~=~ \gamma m_1 m_2 \int^r_{\infty} \frac{d\rho}{\rho^2}   
~=~ - \frac{\gamma m_1 m_2}{r}.\tag{2}
$$

However is it possible to derive this formula without presupposing the formula for $F_{\mathrm{G}}$? (I want to derive the formula of $F_G$ from that of $E_{\mathrm{pot}}$ and don't want to have a circular reasoning).

If so, is there a derivation which is intuitive in some way and how do do it in detail?

Comment: You might be able to determine this by observing the motion of celestial bodies, like Kepler did. And look at the change of kenetic energy as a function of the radius. But you will end up with an experimental model and not some mathematical derivation, since this would require some assumptions, such as the gravitational force.

Comment: A derivation starting from what? You can't just deduce gravitation from nothing; at some point you need experiment to provide you with a formula.

Comment: @That's clear. The deduction should start from a point which should be as intuitive as possible or (at least in special cases) accessible by not so complicated (Gedanken)experiments.

Answer (score 2):

One could start from the more general Poisson equation for a mass distribution $\rho$, namely $\nabla^2 E_{pot} = 4 \pi G \rho$ and infer that the solution to this equation for a point mass $\rho = m_1 \delta$ is the familiar $1/r$ potential. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity#Poisson.27s_equation_and_gravitational_potential). Then one would derive the force from the usual prescription $F = -\nabla (m_2 E_{pot})$.

As for a more intuitive derivation, I would suppose one to exist but don't know one offhand. Try Newton's *Principia* or the Feynman lectures.

Answer (score 0):

The only thoughts I have ever had is that you may/should be able to reproduce the GR explained visibility of stars positioned behind the Sun using some sort of lensing effect due to light's intetaction with gravitons. If you can do anything with lasers and horseshoe shaped lenses. Imagine what you could do with gravitons;-)

Answer (score 0):

With the wisdom of some years I have a more interesting answer to advance.

The intensity of a constant stream of particles from a point-source emanating equally in all directions decreases according to an inverse-square law. It's inverse-*square* because 2 = 3 spatial dimensions - 1. Modern quantum field theory postulates that field interactions are mediated by the transmission of the respective field carrier boson, implying the inverse-square laws of the field strengths for static gravitational and electric fields.